# Stats from our current SailsJS server

Tags: node.js, sails.js, node-request

How to get or inspect these statistics, such as traffic requests, memory usage, etc., from our Sails application. Is there a relevant library to do this?

Answer (score 1):

We use [PM2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2) along with [Keymetrics](https://keymetrics.io/).
PM2 also provides lots of features that you want to use anyway like keeping the app alive (like [Forever](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever)), clusters your app if desired and much more.

Other options are NewRelic and other more expensive options. A keyword here is **[APM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_performance_management)**.

Comment: It is a good method to see it externally, but will there be an api to see this data inside our website?